# Create Checking Permission function in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I create 1 loginForm, this form will check email and password, if them typed like info in database, redirect to mainForm.
Addition, I want to create and check id, if id = '1' => admin, show mainForm, if not show Error Msg.
Because anyone can Login and manage info in database
my database have 1 table included 7 fields: id, email, password, fullname, sex, birth, address
AccountBUS.Cs:

```
AccountManagementDataContext AccMgr = new
AccountManagementDataContext();
        public bool CheckLogin(string email, string password)
        {
            int account = (from acc in AccMgr.BasicInfos
                           where acc.email == email && acc.password == password
                           select acc).Count();
            if (account == 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        }
        public IEnumerable<BasicInfo> SelectAll()
        {
            IEnumerable<BasicInfo> account = from acc in AccMgr.BasicInfos
                                             select acc;
            return account;
        }
        public bool CheckAccount(string email)
        {
            int account = (from acc in AccMgr.BasicInfos
                           where acc.email == email
                           select acc).Count();
            if (account == 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;

        }
```

How I can make checking id function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var isAdmin = AccMgr.BasicInfos.Where(account => account.Email == email & account.Password == password).Select(account => account.Id) == 1;

if(isAdmin) 
{
    // put your logic here.
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this solution, it's to rigid and hard-coded. What if you ever need more than one admin account? Or for some reason you delete this account and another one is created that happens to get ID==1?

a better way would be to add a column `HasAdminPriviliges` then you can simply check for that flag:

```
bool isAdmin = AccMgr.BasicInfos.Any(acc => acc.email == email &&
                                     acc.HasAdminPrivileges == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a column with the role. If you use the code first, then you can do so

add a enum

```
public enum Role
{
    User = 1,
    Admin = 2
}
```

and a property in the model

```
public virtual Role Role {get; set; }
```

then

```
bool isAdmin = AccMgr.BasicInfos.Any (acc => acc.email == email &&
                                      acc.Role == Role.Admin);
```